# Language Translation in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a website in ASP.NET which will be used globally. There is a requirement to provide a language translation option at the home page where the user will be able to select a language and the page(s) will be rendered in that. I have heard of Google translation service but have no idea how to use them. Can anyone provide some links/suggestion that can guide me in this?

Regards.

Comment: This is what rocks StackOverflow. You ask a question and someone is always there to answer. A LIVING AND BREATHING EXAMPLE OF COMMUNITY.Thanks Icarus.

Comment: My pleasure and good luck with your site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the [instructions here](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools) and you'll be good to go, but essentially, all you need to do is include this code:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en'
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Into every page that you want to allow the user to be able to translate.